# How do i size the width of this border around text?

Tags: html, css

I want to control the size of the border around this text, it goes all the way across the page. How do I do this?

```
<p style="border-style: solid;border-width: 1px;border-color: cyan;">Black and Yellow.</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a `span` instead since it is an inline element. `p`s are block elements.

```
<p>
  <span style="border-style: solid;border-width: 1px;border-color: cyan;">Black and Yellow.</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Ah, thank you. So, how does the span element make it go dead around the text, but the paragraph tag makes it go across the whole page?

Comment: @z33_d00g thats the difference between inline and block elements.